# Does opening a source code site actually load contents when displaying?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, web

Does opening a source code site actually load contents of that page (any engines, scripts, images, fonts. Etc) when displaying? If only typed ViewSource: then url from new tab or blank page, it just redirects it to search engine. I currently view source code by opening a page>context menu>then ViewSource, then either bookmarking that page, then after loading, paste the new page URL that I want to  view.

Also what's best & most easy shortcut method to ViewSource code of a page in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When a browser Loads a page normally, it downloads the html document indicated by the URL and start rendering the code. First, it will read the head section, and begin loading each document listed there (generally script files, css stylesheets, etc). It will add script code to the document, and render the markup, executing onLoad scripts, perhaps loading additional remote content, and finally applying the CSS rules in order. This is a fully rendered page.

When you don't use an engine to render the page (using the browser View Source, or tools like wget/curl), you just get the original markup document. No sub links are processed, and no remote source imported.

Generally speaking, if you want to examine rendered contents, you use the Developer tools available in most common browsers (usually on F12, so you can just tap it).

A friend of mine once wrote a scraper for a site, where the content was injected into the page at runtime by a CMS framework. She had to embed an invisible browser control into her app and fully render the page with scripts (window-less flash ads would just appear from nowhere) before she could access the complete source to parse it for a hard-link to the content.